# comparing two columns and print them in ascending order

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file in which i wanted to compare two columns and arrange them according to ascending order

```
File 1

name1 300 200
name2 200 400
name3 100 50
name4 500 1000
name5 1000 800

output

name1 200 300
name2 200 400
name3 50 100
name4 500 1000
name5 800 1000
```

to compare and print smaller value in second column.

Comment: Please show both files you want to compare and show us the desired output.

Comment: Also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: You said you had two files. You're showing us one file and the expected output (I presume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be as easy as:

```
awk '$2>$3{t=$3;$3=$2;$2=t}7' file
```

- If you want to check the last two columns, you can change `$3 -> $NF` and `$2->$(NF-1)`
- The swap part is common skill for all programming languages.
- Hope you've learned how to fish this time.

Comment: can you explain the logic please?